# the food the church cooks vs the church-cooked food

Tags: sentence-construction

The church in my neighborhood cooks and gives free food to everyone every Sunday. I am going to make up two similar sentences below.

(1) I like the church-cooked food more than home-cooked food.

(2) I like the food the church cooks more than home-cooked food.

Which one is idiomatic or neither?

Answer (score 2):

I prefer the second option, but I'd adjust it.  "Home-cooked" is a familiar expression. I know that it doesn't literally mean that the home is cooking, but it means cooked at home, you could even just use "home-cooking".  On the other hand cooking at church is less common, so there isn't a well-known expression "church-cooked". I think it is clearer to say "the food cooked at church", than "the food the church cooks". As such it is better to spell out the details:

> I like the food cooked at church better than home-cooking.